# Inducer fan is running but the control board doesn't see it

Tags: switch, pressure, exhaust

My Armstrong 51HWC183A-3B furnace is giving me 2 blinks as an error message. According to the manual, the error means:

> Pressure switch closed while inducer not running

The problem that the inducer is running, that is what is causing the pressure switch to close, but the control board is not receiving a signal that the inducer is running.

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: I would expect that the controller board is (supposed to be) in charge of deciding when the inducer runs. So it looks to me as though the inducer is running when it's not supposed to be running. Possibly the relay on the control board which controls the inducer is stuck on. Does the inducer ever turn off?

Comment: Or the pressure switch has gone bad.

Comment: "that is what is causing the pressure switch to close" - not according to the furnace, which when it tried to start up noticed that it was closed and therefore faulty. Hopefully, otherwise it's the board or some other giant headache. - The inducer still running and it otherwise doing nothing is indicative of a lockout state; purging. And on old Yorks, that *is* the 'error code'.

Comment: Pressure switch closed while inducer not running... proceeding into lockout and beginning purge just to be safe, because it might have no idea where in the cycle it failed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the appropriate tools, disconnect the pressure switch and check the operation of it with a meter, both in the resting and in the activated position. If it's operating correctly, it's likely to be a circuit board problem. If it's stuck shorted or open, leaks until it opens, etc, you have a pressure switch problem. This is one of the simplest parts of this furnace to troubleshoot as there's nothing in the circuit except the switch and the control board.